# How to enable scrollbar on a disabled textarea in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, textarea, scrollbar

In IE (I use Edge but it's the same for previous version), there is no scrollbar on a textarea with disable attribute.
Is there some css that could display it ?

Answer (score 0):

**Put text area inside div then fix the height of div and scroll the div.**